# Impossible to create new instance of a type defined in module M1 in a function defined in another module M2

Tags: module, scope, julia

I am currently learning this great Julia language but I am facing a difficulty for which my best friend Google doesn't seem to have answer (maybe my searching skills are bad).

Anyway... My context is the following :

I have two modules :

1. M1.jl

   ```
   module M1
   type T
       t1::Int64
   end

   T() = T(0)

   export T
   end
   ```
2. M2.jl

   ```
   module M2
   function create()
        isdefined(:T) ? T() : "undef"
   end

   export create
   end
   ```

I just want to call the `create` function to instantiate an object of type `T` if the type is defined. Here what I've tried to do (modules `M1` and `M2` are assumed in the path) :

```
using M1; 
using M2;

create()
```

Then I got this `ERROR: UndefVarError: T not defined` whereas I'd have expected to get `M1.T(0)` since `T` is known in the interpreter or at least `"undef"` if module `M1` wasn't loaded in my session.

In addition if I do that :
    using M1; 
    using M2;

```
isdefined(:T) ? T() : "undef"
```

Then everything's fine, I get : `M1.T(0)`

So my questions are :

1. Is is possible to make the function `create` "see"  the types defined in modules loaded in the current session?
2. Could you please explain whay I got this error `ERROR: UndefVarError: T not defined` since if `T` was not defined in my context, `isdefined` must have returned `false` such that `"undef"` should have been returned?

Many thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Why can't you pass in the actual type to `create`? No matter what, `M2` clearly depends on `M1`, so the dependency has to be mediated in some way.

Comment: Sorry for the argument of function `create`, it's copy-paste mistake... Thanks by the way. Right, `M2`depends on `M1` but I thought it will be a way to satisfy this dependency via module `Main`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julia Doc describes the functionality of `isdefined()` as follow:

> With a single symbol argument, tests whether a global variable with that name is defined in **current_module()**.

But which module is the **current_module()**?

To find an answer for the above question I've added a `whatiscurrentmodule()` function to `M2`, and load it into `Main` what I've got is this:

```
julia> module M2

         function whatiscurrentmodule()
           println("current_module=",current_module())
         end

         function create(type_name::AbstractString)
              isdefined(:T) ? T() : "undef"
         end
         export create
         println("current_module=",current_module())
       end;
current_module=M2  

julia> M2.whatiscurrentmodule()
current_module=Main # current_module is the caller module
```

Now it's clear what was happened in run-time: `isdefined()` returns `true` because `:T` is defined in the caller scope but `T()` could not fined `:T` because it is not imported into `M2`, to overcome this issue, one could force `M2` to use `M1`:

```
julia> module M2
         using M1
         function create(type_name::AbstractString)
             isdefined(:T) ? T() : "undef"
         end
         export create
       end;

julia> using M1

julia> M2.create("")
M1.T(0)
```

**EDIT**: or do not import anything but add a full path to `:T`

```
julia> module M2
         function create(type_name::AbstractString)
             isdefined(:T) ? current_module().T() : "undef"
         end
         export create
       end;

julia> using M1

julia> M2.create("")
M1.T(0)
```

Comment: Thanks Reza for your explanation of what's happening with the `isdefined` function. It's clearer now. Your suggestion to force `M2` module into `M1` is ok but in practice my use case is a little bit more complicated (as always). Indeed the `create` function is actually expected be able to create instance of a large number of types (i.e. not only `T `) defined in different modules. But I'll deal with that if there is no "simple" solution to force `create` to see what is defined in `Main`.